# Who gets the bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I have answered [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230224/ubuntu-freeze-when-i-plugged-the-power-cable#comment295154_230224) featured question which has a bounty of +50. I had first answered it through a comment. My comment helped in solving the question. I was asked to re write it as an answer so that i can get the bounty. I did that but my answer has only one up-vote while there is another answer that has three up-votes. The grace period ends in 40 mins. So if that user who had asked the question doesnt come online then the bounty is awarded to the person whose answer has 3 up-votes right? or is there a chance i still get the bounty?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If things stayed as they were, you would not get the bounty. The single highest scored post (as long as it's >+2) gets half the bounty if the bounty expires.

I've cleaned up the post, have left a message and asked the chat room to vote for it. Normally speaking all of the above is frowned upon but I think we have a special set of circumstances.